# Back page but avoiding reload Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Is it there's a way to go back on Windows Phone pages Stack but without reloading the target page? I'm looking for something like the function `finish` on android that just remove the current activity.

The problem that I'm facing is that I have a `pivot` with 3 pages each one with differents action targets when I click on any link to go to another page after I go back the pivot go to the page 1 automatic so I want to preserve the last active page.

Answer (score 0):

[Assuming Silverlight]

One way could be to have a public in app.xaml.cs you can access the values using `((App)Application.Current).YourVariable` If you navigate out of the app (you can verify that in the app.xaml.cs in deactivated and close event, if this happens you might have to save the variable to isolatedstorage, to ensure performance. In other cases you can set the app to preserve state and just use the initial idea with a variable. BUT if it takes a long time before the user returns the app could tombstone, and some reload could occur.

Another and maybe the simple solution just instantiate the pivot upon load to the last page used, this you can do by using the `OnNavigatedFrom` Event to save the current pivot to isolatedstorage. Then you can load that pivot.selectedIndex and set that after `Initialise` of the page has happend. You might need to call updatelayout on the pivot control if you have not implemented `RaisePropertyChanged` or `NotifyPropertyChanged` depending on the code structure/usings :)

Hope it helps a little

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn on NavigationCache.
In xaml.cs constructor just add this line

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```